# What (screen-) colors should I use along with 3d glasses?

Tags: 3d, stereo-3d, stereoscopy

While cleaning up the attic, I found a pair of 3d-glasses with the left "eye" being blue and the right one being red. Just for the fun of it, I then created a program that draws a cube (the edges) in red and blue such that it should appear three dimensional with the 3d glasses.

I chose pure red (255, 0, 0) and pure blue (0, 0, 255) when drawing the cube. As far as I can see, the math is correct, but it feels quite unnatural looking at the cube. I guess this is because the one eye sees the cube in different colors than the right eye.

So, could I enhance the viewing experience by altering the colors? And if so, what colors would I use?

Comment: You can play (at least) Duke Nukem 3D in red-cyan mode, to get the idea. Or, get Bino player (opensource project using ffmpeg and some 3d shaders to process video).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some tricks for producing anaglyphs. While not well written, the Wikipedia article touches on some key points:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaglyph_image

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link. It helped me solve the problem: I should not have used pure blue but #00CCFF.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would view the pdfs on a [page like this](http://suda.co.uk/projects/color/), pick the colours I thought were most appropriate, then find the rgb values of those colours using a [program like this](http://www.colorschemer.com/colorpix_info.php).